# WCF Service not working without namespace

Tags: wcf, namespaces

I have two different installations of a WCF web service.
One is on my local IIS, where the service web.config file has a <service ..> section whose "name" attribute is the same of the class that implements the service itself, and it responds correctly .

Another installation is on a remote machine, and here the <service ..> section in the web.config file has an attribute "name" with the class' namesapce added to it : this is the only way I can make it respond on the remote installation : if I remove the namespace from the "Name" attribute the service respondes with the following error :

> Contract requires TwoWay (either request-reply or duplex), but Binding
> 'NetMsmqBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to
> support it.

while in my local installation the namespace is not required in the name attribute.
I thought that attribute should match the corresponding in the .svc but it doesn't seem the case, since in my local installation the name attribute in the web.config is differente from the one in the .svc, but it works anyway.

What is the meaning of the "name" attribute in the web.config's <service .. > section ?

Answer (score 0):

The service name must be the fully qualified name of your service class, including the namespace, e.g.

```
<service name="YourServiceNamespace.YourService">
```

It can't be just anything - the name of the service class is used by ServiceHost to find the right service configuration.

```
Contract requires TwoWay (either request-reply or duplex), but Binding
'NetMsmqBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.
```

About this error could also be for another reason.
Caveats about queued binding in WCF include that all service operations must be one-way because the default queued binding in WCF does not support duplex communication using queues.
You need to change the OperationContract property.Example below:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void YourMethod(YourClass objectHere)
```

Comment: Does the WCF runtime first look in the .svc's Service attribute and the tries to match it with a <service > section (in the web.config ) with the same name ? if so , I cannot understand why in the local installation it works anyway no matter if they' re different or the same . As far as the error is concerned I don't know why it comes out since the binding is a basuc Http binding and not a named pipe or MSMQ binding ...

Comment: Maybe you can provide the code for the local and remote machine web.config.

Comment: My local configuration:       
Service.svc   = <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Ti.Pdp.St.IntSP.ST_local.Myservice" CodeBehind="Myservice.svc.cs" %>           
web.config =      <service name="Myservice" > ...........  

My remote configuration:  
Service.svc   = <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Ti.Pdp.St.IntSP.ST_local.Myservice" CodeBehind="Myservice.svc.cs" %>            
web.config = <service name ="Ti.Pdp.St.IntSP.ST_local.Myservice" >

Comment: Can you provide a complete web.config file？

Comment: The web.config for both configurations is very big  ... I don't know if I can add it ...that's why I wrote a small part ...

Comment: this is the <service ...> on local installation :                                                       
<service name="RiservePaxService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="pdp_basicHttpBinding" contract="IRiservePaxService" name="RiservePaxService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

Comment: this is the <service ...> on the remote one :                                                            
 <service name="Ti.Pdp.St.IntSP.ST_Vestizione.RiservePaxService">
         <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="pdp_basicHttpBinding" contract="IRiservePaxService" name="RiservePaxService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

Comment: The binding is the same for both configurations , I avoided adding it because its too long